# Export Chartsheet from Excel as PNG format

Tags: python-3.x, excel, spyder, xlsxwriter, win32com

Is there a method to save the Chartsheet in EXCEL as PNG in a folder and import the same PNG file to a MS-Word using python?

The excel shows white blank chartsheet when opened and
error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Export'.

```
xlApp=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(r'Z:desktop/demo.xlsx')
chart = xlApp.Charts('Chart')
chart.Export(r'Z:/desktop/chart.png') 
ExcelWorkBook.Close(True)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Provide any code that you think is relevant to help.

Comment: chartsheet = workbook.add_chartsheet()
                   
                    # Create a chart objectchart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter','subtype': 'straight'})